# What are the benefits of caching an xml sitemap?

Tags: seo, cache, xml-sitemap

Am I right in thinking that when robots crawl the sitemap the load time will be reduced because it is cached which is a good signal and could improve ranking?

If this is correct are there any other benefits?

I understand the negative to caching an xml sitemap is that it will not update the pages until the expiration time.

Comment: Browsers store files for caching using respected expires, crawlers do not... otherwise they would run out of disk space quicker than you can say "out of space". It will make no difference if you cache the site map, or not... Furthermore, maps do not help SEO unless you have crawl issues.

Comment: So why do people cache sitemaps?

Comment: Because some site maps are stored in SQL and when they become large, it can drain the SQL server, so its cached to a static file that is served as a fetch request, and not a query request on the SQL database. Caching a sitemap using head expires makes no sense unless you have lots of visitors visiting your site map. Expires are helpful for returnee visitors on static files that do not change regularly. They are not useful for Crawlers, and other types of bots that ignore caching completely.

Comment: You seem to be mixed up with the type of caching. Expire Caching is different to SQL > Static File Caching.

Comment: Thank you @Simon for clarifying this up for me. I was confused about the different types of caching.